# How blending image mask?

Tags: image-processing, opengl-es, glsl, webgl

How can I apply such a mask

[image: mask]

to get effect such as bokeh

[image: bokeh]

need to blur edge in mask and apply on image texture. How do that?

*Vertex shader:*

```
attribute vec4 a_Position;

    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = a_Position;
    }
```

*Fragment shader:*

```
precision lowp float;

    uniform sampler2D u_Sampler; // textureSampler 
    uniform sampler2D u_Mask; // maskSampler
    uniform vec3 iResolution;

    vec4 blur(sampler2D source, vec2 size, vec2 uv) {

        vec4 C = vec4(0.0);

        float width = 1.0 / size.x;
        float height = 1.0 / size.y;

        float divisor = 0.0;

        for (float x = -25.0; x <= 25.0; x++)
        {
            C += texture2D(source, uv + vec2(x * width, 0.0));
            C += texture2D(source, uv + vec2(0.0, x * height));
            divisor++;
        }
        C*=0.5;

        return vec4(C.r / divisor, C.g / divisor, C.b / divisor, 1.0);

    }

    void main()
    {
        vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
        vec4 videoColor = texture2D(u_Sampler, uv);
        vec4 maskColor = texture2D(u_Mask, uv);
        gl_FragColor = blur(u_Sampler, iResolution.xy, uv);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vec4 blurColor = blur(u_Sampler, iResolution.xy, uv);
gl_FragColor = mix(blurColor, videoColor, maskColor.r);
```

But FYI it's not common to blur in one pass like you have. It's more common to blur in one direction (horizontally), then blur the result of that vertically, then mix the results, blurredTexture, videoTexture, mask.